# Using tfs automated build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, solution

How can i get and set the output folder of each project being built by the xaml template.
Is there an object i can get that will tell me the solution name or path being currently built and set the folder according to the solution name?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The default build template includes 2 options for where to put your outputs, either in one consolidated folder (this is what previous versions of TFS have done by default), or to create a folder for each project that is built.  You set this in the Process tab when editing the build definition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dylan Smith's answer is 100% correct and accurate, **if** you're using the TFS2013 build process template. There are plenty of reasons why you'd be using TFS2013 and not using the TFS2013 build process template (running an older build controller for backwards compatibility reasons, using a heavily modified version of an older build process template, etc).

In those cases, you can get roughly analogous behavior by specifying the MSBuild argument `/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true`.

This only applies to 2012 and 2013; I don't believe 2010 supported this flag.